# accessing addresses in java through TCP connection

Tags: java

I'm attempting read/write to a 64k byte buffer on a server my boss created. While being able to connect to the server through a standard TCP connection, I am rather lost as to how to access the byte buffer itself. Most examples I've employ the use of FileInputStreams, but I am not reading from any file in particular. What I've been told is that the server:

"...creates a 64kbyte buffer that starts out all zeros. You can do VME read/write TCP commands and only the lower 16bits of the address you specify will be used to address this 64kbyte buffer."

So what I am trying to figure out is how do I access this byte buffer to read and write to the addresses on the server.

Forgive me if this is too general, I am very new to both networking and stackoverflow. Thanks :)

Comment: I suspect only you (and your boss) may know what "VME" is in this context.

Answer (score 0):

To access a ByteBuffer by index you can use

```
ByteBuffer bb =
bb.putLong(address, value);
long value = bb.getLong(address);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter!

That will definitely help when it comes to writing to the byte buffer.

But would you know by chance how to actually extract this byte buffer through the socket. Ideally I wish there existed something like"bb = os.getByteBuffer()." I'm just unsure as to actually access the buffer itself.

Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: do you mean `os.read(byteBuffer);` ? If youw ant sample code for reading writeing sockets you can use the code at the bottom of this blog. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-fast-are-java-sockets.html